# Acrobat GST Calculation

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat, tax

I have a preprinted government issued invoice template. I transferred it to Acrobat and made a form. The issue is I have only the following fields:

Subtotal = subtotal
GST Rate = gstrate
Grand Total = where the calculation going to appear

Thus I need to calculate GST dynamically based on the rate entered gstrate field. Can anyone give me a hand? Most of the formulas calculate GST amount and add it to subtotal but I have no chance to do that.

Comment: I can't tell from your question what the field names are or what the exact calculation should be. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hey there only 2 field names are : subtotal and gstrate(percentage)

Comment: Ok - Explain in words what you want the calculation to be. You haven't explained that. I have no idea what a GST Rate means to you.